# How do I see number of or icon for unread messages?

Tags: notifications, settings, notification-icons, push-notifications, instant-messaging

**My device**: I use Android 9 on samsung galaxy s9.

**Background**: I believe there was a feature before (or maybe currently still, but I turned it off) about showing number of unread messages on apps like whatsapp, viber or the SMS app (and i guess gmail or facebook) or at the very least there's some kind of dot or something on a corner of the icon of such an app that indicates there exists at least 1 unread message (so the dot is an alternative to a specific number of unread messages).

**My situation**: I do not have such number or dot on icons on apps on my device. If I get a message on whatsapp or viber or regular SMS but say I have to install some updates and so my phone has to turn off or restart, then the notification of this message is gone.

**Question**: How do I see number or existence of unread messages on icons of apps such as viber and whatsapp and the SMS app?

I have tried looking this up, but

1. I wasn't able to find any articles specifically on Android 9 and Samsung Galaxy S9.
2. The solutions proposed in articles I've found on Android 9 but a different phone or on different versions of Android have not worked for me.
3. I've tried looking up some apps on the play store, but I haven't downloaded any because of the reviews.

Comment: You you are looking for is named icon "Notification Badge". Official Android got this feature very late, therefore a bunch vendor specific API extension exists to trigger such badges on devices  that use Android before this feature was officially introduced. Not sure about S9 on Android 9.

Comment: Nova launcher supports this, don't recall if it is a paid feature

Comment: (part 1) @Robert Oh thanks. I found out, both online and even in settings, badges go away when you swipe...Guess I'll have to resort to...

Comment: (part 2) @beeshyams nova or some other launcher. thanks!

Comment: @BCLC nova does I don't know about others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, both online and even in settings, badges go away when you swipe...Guess I'll have to resort to nova or some other launcher.

---

Some sources:

---

Source 1:

DudeThatsErin
It goes by what is in your status bar. If you swipe them away the number will disappear.

dark_sage94
They notification bar disappears for me once I read one text

LoyalRoyal18
Nova launcher does what you want, I believe.

https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS9/comments/9e66n7/notifications_badge_on_icon_disappears_even/

---

Source 2:

Eh can't find anymore right now

Answer (score 0):

With an ASUS Zenfone do the following: Pinch-in at the Home screen, then go to Preferences > Home screen > App icon badges to complete the setting.

On other phones you may want to press a few seconds the homescreen and then 'home preferences' or similar